# Layout with 3 columns of different sizes using Flex

Tags: css, layout, flexbox

I have a section of the site that must contain three elements side by side. Each element has a minimum width. If the width of the screen is not sufficient to contain all three elements, those that do not fit, go into a new line.

To build this layout I used [Flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). 
[**Code**](https://plnkr.co/edit/jAtSd1aCn4Cz6B0VOXa6?p=preview).

html:

```
<main id='main'>
    <div id='firstRow' class='row'>
        <div id='col1C' class='col'>col1C title
            <div id='col1Ccon'>col1Ccon content</div>
        </div>
        <div id='col2C' class='col'>col2C title
            <div id='col2Ccon'>col2Ccon content</div>
        </div>
        <div id='col3C' class='col'>col3C title
            <div id='col3Ccon'>col3Ccon content</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

css:

```
:root {
    --w1Col: 478px;
    --w2Col: 370px;
    --w3Col: 350px;
    --wSum3: calc(var(--w1Col) + var(--w2Col) + var(--w3Col));
}

html {
    /*height: 100%;*/
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

/***************************************************************
 * Layout first row
 */
#main {
    background-color: white;
    /*border: 4px solid red;*/
    color: black;
    height: 100%;
    flex-grow: 1; /* ability for a flex item to grow if necessary */
    flex-shrink: 0; /* ability for a flex item to shrink if necessary */
    flex-basis: auto; /* defines the default size of an element before the remaining space is distributed */
}

#firstRow {
    background-color: white;
    /*border: 1px solid black;*/
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row; /* colums layout */
    flex-wrap: wrap; /* wrap in multiple lines if it's necessary */
    /*min-width: var(--wSum3);*/
    /*justify-content: flex-end;  defines the alignment along the main axis */
}

#firstRow .col {
    /*border: 1px solid black;*/
    flex: 1;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

#col1C {
    background-color: green;
    width: var(--w1Col);
    min-width: var(--w1Col);
    order: 1; /* column order */
    flex-basis: 40%;/*var(--w1Col);  column width */
    justify-content: flex-end;

}
#col2C {
    background-color: blue;
    width: var(--w2Col);
    min-width: var(--w2Col);
    order: 2; /* column order */
    flex-basis: 35%; /* var(--w2Col);  column width */
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
#col3C {
    background-color:  red;
    width: var(--w3Col);
    min-width: var(--w3Col);
    order: 3; /* column order */
    flex-basis: 25%; /*var(--w3Col);  column width */
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

#col1Ccon, #col2Ccon, #col3Ccon {
    /*border: 1px solid black;*/
    margin: 0 auto; /* center content */
}

#col1Ccon {
    width: var(--w1Col);
    background-color: lightgreen;
    height: 200px;
}
#col2Ccon {
    width: var(--w2Col);
    background-color: lightblue;
    height: 150px;
}
#col3Ccon {
    width: var(--w3Col);
    background-color: salmon;
    height: 200px;
}
```

The code works but there are some tricks I would like to fix.

1. the 3 columns all have the same width and I would like to be able to choose this width. This is because the first element has a minimum width greater than the other two, so the edge is smaller and aesthetically ugly. See [the same example](https://jsfiddle.net/6rys2xe5/4/), I changed only colors
2. the remaining space now grows on both sides of the `col*Ccon` containers. Instead I would like to grow only on the left side of `col1Ccon` and on the right side `col3Ccon`. I would therefore like the contents of the site (`col1Ccon + col2Ccon + col3Ccon`) to always remain in the center of the page and what changes are the "border" that grow and decrease.

I'm stuck and any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve, but I made a simplified example here: https://codepen.io/wiiiiilllllll/pen/vrQzWX Does this help?

Comment: Please post images of the desired results, because I don't really get what you are after either.

Comment: Have you tried media queries? I found a codepen but it could disappear -->https://codepen.io/estelle/pen/brDpB

Answer (score 1):

The reason your columns all have the same width, is because you gave a `flex: 1` to the col class. In this case that means that every column (which is all of them) has one third of the screen available for them. What you can do is remove the `flex` property from the col class and instead use it in the scope of the id selectors of the columns. So in the code below I put the `flex` property in the id selectors, with a small difference that the second column gets a `flex-grow` property of 0 with it (The first value in the `flex` property). The first column is slightly bigger like you said, so it takes a little more space.

Then, to keep the content centered: The first part is to give that second column a `flex-grow` of 0, so it stays in the middle. The other two columns do grow, and with an automatic `margin` on one side of the content columns, it will grow on one side and the content column will be aligned to either the left or the right to give an idea of centered content. This is only for a bigger screen, for smaller screens you can use media queries to align the content correctly.

So in the end, your code may look like this. I don't know if this was exactly what you had in mind, but you can play around with it and see if it works.

```
:root {
    --w1Col: 478px;
    --w2Col: 370px;
    --w3Col: 350px;
    --wSum3: calc(var(--w1Col) + var(--w2Col) + var(--w3Col));
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

/***************************************************************
 * Layout first row
 */
#main {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    height: 100%;
    flex: 1 0 auto; 
    width: 100%;
}

#firstRow {
    background-color: white;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row; /* colums layout */
    flex-wrap: wrap; /* wrap in multiple lines if it's necessary */
}

#firstRow .col {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

#col1C {
    background-color: green;
    order: 1; /* column order */
    flex: 1 1 var(--w1Col);
}
#col2C {
    background-color: blue;
    order: 2; /* column order */
    flex: 0 1 var(--w2Col);
}
#col3C {
    background-color:  red;
    order: 3; /* column order */
    flex: 1 1 var(--w3Col);
}

#col1Ccon {
    max-width: var(--w1Col);
    background-color: lightgreen;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 0 0 auto;
}

#col2Ccon {
    max-width: var(--w2Col);
    background-color: lightblue;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#col3Ccon {
    max-width: var(--w3Col);
    background-color: salmon;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1268px) {
  #col2C {
    flex-grow: 1;
  }

  #col2Ccon {
    margin: 0 auto 0 0;
  }

  #col3Ccon {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 908px) {
  #col1Ccon {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  #col2Ccon {
    margin: 0 0 0 auto;
  }

  #col3Ccon {
    margin: 0 auto 0 0;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 780px) {
  #col2Ccon, #col3Ccon {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
```

As for the second question

Answer (score 0):

**Replace your style sheet mey be your issue solve**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
}
#firstRow {
    background-color: white;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#firstRow .col {
    flex: 1;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

#col1C {
    background-color: green;
}
#col2C {
    background-color: blue;
}
#col3C {
    background-color: red;
}

#col1Ccon, #col2Ccon, #col3Ccon {
    margin: 0 auto; 
}

#col1Ccon {
    background-color: lightgreen;
    height: 200px;
}
#col2Ccon {
    background-color: lightblue;
    height: 200px;
}
#col3Ccon {
    background-color: salmon;
    height: 200px;
}
```